# What is an aftermarket devise that performs a convenient navigation of a phone?

Tags: mouse-pad

Is there a touch pad that goes over the screen or mouse that would allow navigation to a phone in which the main touch screen is no longer working?
So many times I could have used something like this. I can see everything fine but the crack messes up the touch screen.

I'm not having a conflict between 2 pieces of hardware. I was hoping someone could tell me if there is such hardware.

Comment: What sort of price range are you looking for? What phone are you buying this for?

Comment: @ArtOfCode how is this to broad? Any phone? I'm not having a conflict between 2 pieces of hardware. I was hoping someone could tell me if there is such hardware?

Comment: Minor difference between "too broad" (which is a system close reason) and "requirements too broad" (which is a HR-specific custom reason). The requirements you've specified in this question aren't detailed enough for us to be able to recommend the best hardware; that's why I asked some questions above. If you can tell us the price point and phone you're buying for, that should be enough detail to work with.

Comment: In general, there isn't really hardware that exists for this case. Also I noticed you re-edited your question, however; we need a budget limit so that we can offer you the **best** solution to your problem, particularly if we cannot find a clear touch pad. If you are still hoping to get a recommendation for a 'clear, paste-able touch pad' you'll need to at least tell us your phone model, and screen dimensions.

Comment: @BennettYeo it doesn't have to be limited to a clear touch screen pad. Could just be a mouse or pad that allows me to navigate the screen on any model.

Comment: If you are simply looking for a recommendation for 'Method of convenient navigation on a phone', the question can be reworded to fit our guidelines and **possibly** re-opened. What you've described in your comment is much more likely to exist. If you still need help, I can try to help edit your question, or you can delete this question and ask what you've described in your comment as a new, separate question. Please keep in mind, we still need a **budget** and **phone model/type** to give you the best recommendation possible.

Comment: @BennettYeo yes. What is an aftermarket devise that performs a convenient navigation of a phone?